# Durandal and Jasmine: dependency mock

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, jasmine, durandal

I'm facing a problem trying to mock some of the Durandal dependencies... For example, I have this in my viewmodel (on the activate function):

```
routerFirstActiveFragment = router.activeInstruction().fragment.toLowerCase().split('/')[0];
```

I want to mock the router plugin, so, in my test file I have this:

```
define(['viewmodels/testvm', 'plugins/router'], function (testvm, router) {
    describe('Module test', function () {
        it('a test', function () {
            spyOn(router, 'activeInstruction').andReturn('/get/33');
            testvm.activate();
        });
    });
});
```

The thing is that when I do that, I receive this message when I run the test

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
```

So, what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it works like this:

```
spyOn(router, 'activeInstruction').andCallFake(function () {
    return {
        fragment: "/get/33"
    };
});
```